# Can I use action='POST' to PHP from contact form in React JS?

Tags: php, reactjs, forms, email, form-submit

I have tried to post form data from a React JS rendered form, calling aq php file with the action part of the form... I have uploaded the form and the attached PHP file to my website, but when the form is filled out out submitted, no email is sent, and the url changes back to the homepage with the name of the PHP file tagged on (index.js/contact.php).

Is my code below bad?

Or is this just not possible to do using a combination of React JS and PHP?

contactMe.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ContactMe extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='contact-body'>
                    <div className='contact-right'>
                        <div className='contact-side'>
                            <h2 style={{ fontSize: '25px', fontFamily: 'Anton', paddingTop: '10px'}}>
                                Contact Me
                        </h2>
                            <hr />
                            <div className='contact-list'>
                                <div className='form'>
                                    <form action="contact.php" method='post'>
                                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name..." />
                                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email..." />
                                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message me..."></textarea>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ContactMe;
```

contact.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $userName = $_POST['name'];
  $userEmail = $_POST['email'];
  $userMessage = $_POST['message'];

  $emailSubject = 'New Message From My Website Visitor';
  $emailBody = 'Visitor Name: ' . $userName . '\n\n' .
    'Visitor Email: ' . $userEmail . '\n\n' .
    'Message: ' . $userMessage . '\n\n';

  $emailTo = 'james_ross@outlook.fr';

  $headers = 'From: ' . $emailFrom . '\n\n';

  mail($emailTo, $emailSubject, $emailBody, $headers);

  header('Location: index.js/mailsent');
}
```

If I need to use another technique/language in place of the PHP, please advise me of s decent source to read up on it, Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

`action="contact.php"` is a relative link and it looks like your frontend runs as `xxx/index.js/`, you have to set it to an absolute url like `action="/contact.php"` or `action="xxx/contact.php"` where xxx is the folder with your php script.

If you develop with react than you don't want to switch between server side and client side pages, just send your form with ajax and display the output in your react app.

Your PHP code has a security issue:
$emailFrom is not defined, if you have some old PHP configuration with register_globals than it is possible to insert own header content and f.e. send spam emails to any email addresses.

Comment: I will try the small change in the action part of the form tag.

But you talk about displaying the output in my react app - but I'm aiming to have aa contact form that when submitted would send me an email. Or maybe I've misunderstood you?

Comment: No good, I tried with the adjustment you recommended but no email comes through after a few minutes of waiting...